# css - changing css color of svg and path

Tags: html, css

I am trying to eliminate the dark navy color that is attached to the css waves - so that the sky blue waves blend into a simple white background. I am not sure how to accomplish this - it may have to do with the svg and the path.

https://codepen.io/rblanc/pen/oNXJzed

I have tried to change the css code

```
.color {
/* background: #3498db; */
background: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Your codepen link isn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

by adding the tag

> fill = white

and changing the background of the svg to blue you will achieve your target

```css
svg{
  background-color: #3498db;
}
```

```html
  <!-- WAVES -->
  <svg id="stamp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none" fill="white">
    <path d="M0 0 Q 2.5 40 5 0 
       Q 7.5 40 10 0
       Q 12.5 40 15 0
       Q 17.5 40 20 0
       Q 22.5 40 25 0
       Q 27.5 40 30 0
       Q 32.5 40 35 0
       Q 37.5 40 40 0
       Q 42.5 40 45 0
       Q 47.5 40 50 0 
       Q 52.5 40 55 0
       Q 57.5 40 60 0
       Q 62.5 40 65 0
       Q 67.5 40 70 0
       Q 72.5 40 75 0
       Q 77.5 40 80 0
       Q 82.5 40 85 0
       Q 87.5 40 90 0
       Q 92.5 40 95 0
       Q 97.5 40 100 0 Z">
    </path>
   </svg>
```